# tk: do I need to mention the widget master?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to rearrange frames in PanedWindows at runtime based upon user request. Previously I specified the master for each frame (here pw1). Ex:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

pw1 = tk.PanedWindow(orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, sashpad=2,
    sashwidth=4, sashrelief=tk.RAISED)
pw1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

frame1 = tk.Frame(pw1, bg='red',width=100, height=100) 
frame2 = tk.Frame(pw1, bg ='yellow',width=100,height=100)

# This seems to do the same thing:
# frame1 = tk.Frame(bg='red',width=100, height=100) # vs. tk.Frame()
# frame2 = tk.Frame(bg ='yellow',width=100,height=100) 

pw1.add(frame1, sticky=tk.NSEW)
pw1.add(frame2, sticky=tk.NSEW)

root.mainloop()
```

What is the advantage of specifying the master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `master` paremeter can be interpreted as `parent`. Passing this will add a new key in the `parent.children` attribute.

If you print `pw1.children` when you do not pass `master` **AND** do not execute `pw1.add()` you will see that it returns an empty dictionary.

```
print pw1.children
#{}
```

The `pw1.add()` method also includes the added widget in the `pw1.children` dictionary. I still did not understand why when you pass `master` the widgets are not automatically shown.

Comment: The widgets automatically showed just fine with or without the master parameter. Rearranging the frames worked well only when the master was not specified. So it sounds that specifying the master is generally redundant.